# web.1: crashed ERROR when scaling dyno on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, port

I just deployed my app on heroku. Then I ran:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Which ran ok, but when I wanted to check the dyno working with heroku ps I got the following:

```
=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: crashed 2015/01/19 11:18:38 (~ 3m ago)
```

heroku logs:

```
2015-01-19T15:14:06.131511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=rock-paper-scissors-test.herokuapp.com 
request_id=27ca44cb-ca4e-473e-9789-0245d393bd56 
fwd="190.15.209.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

get the following line before exiting on heroku logs:

```
2015-01-19T15:28:57.189329+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2015-01-19T15:28:57.922629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error that wasn't being addressed in the logs. I had to run:

```
heroku run console
```

to get the details. Just like they advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try the suggestion you're receiving in the logs:

```
Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
```

Change your Procfile to:

```
bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV --binding 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: thenks @diego.greybot but it was actually about a constant missing. The thing is it wasnt in the logs.