# Web.1 Showing as crashed immediately on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

When following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#visit-your-application) and getting to the steps in the link, my web.1 dyno crashes immediately.  I have not changed anything they did say to in the guide. I then tried to ensure that my database was created with `heroku run:detached rake db:migrate` and that timed out.

Any information would be great.

Comment: Do you find any errors in heroku logs?

Comment: I don't know if these are related but if they are I don't know how to really read them:
'2016-10-16T17:40:32.400260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bcstoreapp.herokuapp.com request_id=474e7cd2-90a5-4daf-af05-2f0b95901ca8 fwd="64.183.182.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027836/web-1-crashed-error-when-scaling-dyno-on-heroku)
There was an error that wasn't being addressed in the logs. So you had to run:

```
heroku run rails console
```

Some errors doesn't appear on heroku dashboard, so try debug it, or past the log result here.

Or like some other tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed?rq=1):
scale down and scale back up the dynos:

```
heroku ps:scale web=0
```

Waited a few seconds...

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```