# heroku run rake db:migrate error for rails and mysql project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i have a project with rails 4.2 and mysql database. but when i do `heroku run rake db:migrate` result is:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1461
/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory
```

and i don't have bin in my .gitignore.

in my heroku logs i have two errors:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=serene-ocean-1351.herokuapp.com request_id=a40f485d-e55e-4246-b863-a8b13a3b89fa fwd="199.189.106.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-ocean-1351.herokuapp.com request_id=3404e956-71db-4530-be1f-ce6f3f23a857 fwd="199.189.106.136" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed

Comment: when i run `heroku run rails console`, i get this error: `/usr/bin/env: ruby2.2: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

Look up files in the bin directory of the project, in the first line will be

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby2.2
```

you have to simply change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have just upgraded to Rails 4 then try the following to update Heroku's binaries to support your commands.

`$ heroku run rake rails:update:bin --app serene-ocean-1351`