# Heroku database error? Cannot Rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been stuck on this for hours. I've been going back and forth with rollbacks and heroku has been crashing on me. The error I've been getting is Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I've tried heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL and then heroku rake db:migrate many many many times and it still prompts that error each time.

Here are my logs

```
    2015-08-20T03:53:52.883786+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: Awaiting client
2015-08-20T03:53:52.917990+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-08-20T03:53:53.287377+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-20T03:53:58.412740+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: Process exited with status 0
2015-08-20T03:53:58.432909+00:00 heroku[run.7282]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-20T03:54:04.586682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=linkmony.herokuapp.com request_id=f90ecec2-49f5-4faa-9736-40bdeb637b5e fwd="76.103.13.109" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-08-20T03:54:05.400560+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=linkmony.herokuapp.com request_id=44fb2fae-15b8-4359-bbbb-47c59b2a7d3b fwd="76.103.12.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Have a look at this issue, there are lot of possible issues that could lead to 'App crashed' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed

Comment: Repeating the same scenario is definitely not going to help but frustrate you. Try running your app in production mode locally.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following in terminal should give you more info:

```
$ heroku run rails console
```

(hat tip: ntimba20)