# Rails on Heroku crashes on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I get their error when I try to deploy my github app to heroku. Any Ideas on what this error means? When I go to the myapp.herokuapp.com url I get a default Application message "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments."

```
2015-12-12T20:09:58.118155+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144431+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144434+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:56551
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144436+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-12-12T20:10:00.089633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=5c027f8f6-edc9-130c-80e3-e09852315e1d5 fwd="90.252.159.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-12-12T20:09:58.118155+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144436+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144431+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-12-12T20:09:58.118153+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144435+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144434+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:56551
2015-12-12T20:09:58.144436+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-12-12T20:09:58.907129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-12-12T20:09:58.911994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

UPDATE:

I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` successfully and get an error that is a little different.

```
        2015-12-14T14:46:11.598744+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-12-14T14:46:11.598746+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    2015-12-14T14:46:11.632494+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:20732
    2015-12-14T14:46:12.680393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-12-14T18:20:23.431655+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2ed5f19a-bc65-40b8-ac3b-574d46c35ece fwd="177.127.367.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
: Not found
```

Comment: If you add the repository, I will take a look on it.

Comment: The github repo is private . Anyway I could solve this without posting the repository? Thanks

Comment: Can you start the server in development (on your own machine)? Is this your first deploy to Heroku?

Comment: Basically Rails is crashing on startup - the error is most likely somewhere in your config or initializers. The `heroku[router]:` line is Heroku serving the static error page which you saw in the browser.

Comment: Yes I can successfully start the server locally. And yes this is my first deploy to Heroku. Thanks for all the info

Comment: are you using postgres and pg gem in development? this post might be helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell anything from the log, which suggests the problem is at environment level (you don't have the correct `ENV` var, or more likely, you don't have your database set up correctly).

As a rule of thumb, I've found Heroku to work quite well *unless* you forget to migrate your database.

--

I'll delete this answer if it's wrong, but you'll be best firing:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This will make sure you have the database set up in the Heroku environment. Whether it's the problem is another matter; I've found that 9/10 times, not having a db / not migrating the db in Heroku is the biggest reason for the application crashing.

Comment: I ran the command you suggested and got a little different error. Please take a look at my update. Thank you