# Heroku deployment error H10 App crashed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I have a RoR app running locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku the App crashes with the H10 error.

As already stated in multiple questions, the error logs aren't very helpful. I followed all possible answers given for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed) question, but everything seems fine:

1. 'git push heroku master' - deployment worked fine
2. 'heroku run rake db:migrate' - Migrations worked fine (Initially had to modify one of the migrations file since it was throwing an error around 'casting to integer type' directly
3. Tried 'heroku restart' and 'heroku run rails console' - Both commands worked fine but the app still crashes. Rails console is working fine.

Would be really great if someone could help me figure out the problem. Any pointers on how to debug would be helpful too since the logs are not revealing much.

Thanks in advance!

The logs are as follows:

> 2017-02-07T12:54:24.270796+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ccdb832 by user
>   hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com 2017-02-07T12:54:24.707255+00:00
>   app[api]: Release v7 created by user hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com
>   2017-02-07T12:54:25.059219+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   crashed to starting 2017-02-07T12:54:30.496466+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
>   2017-02-07T12:54:33.433084+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not
>   found: puma 2017-02-07T12:54:33.433103+00:00 app[web.1]: Install
>   missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>   2017-02-07T12:54:33.547470+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2017-02-07T12:54:33.548434+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   State changed from crashed to starting
>   2017-02-07T12:54:33.533288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 127 2017-02-07T12:54:39.076000+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting
>   process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
>   2017-02-07T12:54:41.312542+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not
>   found: puma 2017-02-07T12:54:41.312561+00:00 app[web.1]: Install
>   missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>   2017-02-07T12:54:41.273272+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle install` by user hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com
>   2017-02-07T12:54:41.437332+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2017-02-07T12:54:41.406962+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2017-02-07T12:54:46.473525+00:00
>   heroku[run.3853]: Awaiting client 2017-02-07T12:54:46.699719+00:00
>   heroku[run.3853]: Starting process with command `bundle install`
>   2017-02-07T12:54:46.645765+00:00 heroku[run.3853]: State changed from
>   starting to up 2017-02-07T12:54:56.711109+00:00 heroku[run.3853]:
>   Process exited with status 0 2017-02-07T12:54:56.721230+00:00
>   heroku[run.3853]: State changed from up to complete
>   2017-02-07T12:55:06.351307+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user
>   hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com 2017-02-07T12:55:11.878496+00:00
>   heroku[run.9062]: Awaiting client 2017-02-07T12:55:11.910846+00:00
>   heroku[run.9062]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake
>   db:migrate` 2017-02-07T12:55:12.003058+00:00 heroku[run.9062]: State
>   changed from starting to up 2017-02-07T12:55:19.873613+00:00
>   heroku[run.9062]: Process exited with status 1
>   2017-02-07T12:55:19.885944+00:00 heroku[run.9062]: State changed from
>   up to complete 2017-02-07T12:57:38.720579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State
>   changed from crashed to starting 2017-02-07T12:57:38.465627+00:00
>   app[api]: Release v8 created by user hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com
>   2017-02-07T12:57:38.465627+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a1c8e6d by user
>   hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com 2017-02-07T12:57:38.597661+00:00
>   heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
>   2017-02-07T12:57:38.597673+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug
>   compilation finished 2017-02-07T12:57:38.642076+00:00 app[api]:
>   Release v8 created by user hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com
>   2017-02-07T12:57:43.187357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
>   2017-02-07T12:57:45.183178+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not
>   found: puma 2017-02-07T12:57:45.183197+00:00 app[web.1]: Install
>   missing gem executables with `bundle install`
>   2017-02-07T12:57:45.314860+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed 2017-02-07T12:57:45.301215+00:00 heroku[web.1]:
>   Process exited with status 127 2017-02-07T12:57:59.399411+00:00
>   app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
>   by user hrishikeshpardeshi@gmail.com 2017-02-07T12:58:04.149041+00:00
>   heroku[run.7804]: Awaiting client 2017-02-07T12:58:04.193819+00:00
>   heroku[run.7804]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake
>   db:migrate` 2017-02-07T12:58:04.384181+00:00 heroku[run.7804]: State
>   changed from starting to up 2017-02-07T12:58:11.107702+00:00
>   heroku[run.7804]: Process exited with status 0
>   2017-02-07T12:58:11.116829+00:00 heroku[run.7804]: State changed from
>   up to complete 2017-02-07T12:58:19.462586+00:00 heroku[router]:
>   at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=fast-refuge-78538.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=79f2a39b-18a0-440c-8568-77900729062f fwd="14.139.123.62"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-02-07T12:58:24.892436+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=fast-refuge-78538.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=5362493e-5ccc-4377-8540-a144ec15757c fwd="14.139.123.62"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2017-02-07T12:59:43.955445+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>   host=fast-refuge-78538.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=1a58fff9-5c78-4257-af94-8fd01d153a5d fwd="14.139.123.62"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Did you add the 12factor gem?  Helps with error reporting

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? Heroku has problems with <1.9.0. This looks like you have some kind of problem with your `GEM_PATH`

Comment: I am using ruby 2.2.2

Comment: I do have the 12factor gem for production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is trying to use puma `bundler: command not found: puma` which is now the [heroku recommended server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594). 
Try adding puma to your gemfile: `gem 'puma', '~> 3.4'` and then push to heroku again.

Comment: Have you tried running the console and seeing if that crashes?

Comment: Okay, do you have the `puma` gem in you Gemfile and if so is it in a development or production group?

Comment: No, I don't. Should I add that to the Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I would try that, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/594

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135090/discussion-between-noah-and-hrishikesh-pardeshi).

Comment: Thanks Noah! Worked perfectly after adding the 'puma' gem.