# Error deploying Rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I get the following error when trying to access my app on heroku. The app was deployed successfully but I could not access it. When I tried to access the app, the page said "Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details." Here is the heroku logs:

```
 heroku logs
2017-03-21T20:28:21.577989+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578004+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578005+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578007+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578008+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578010+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.749663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578012+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578029+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578030+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578032+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in serv                                                                                                                er'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578033+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578052+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578078+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.578079+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2017-03-21T20:28:21.768673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c                                                                                                                rashed
2017-03-21T20:28:23.139347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra                                                                                                                shed" method=GET path="/recipes" host=weather-consult.herokuapp.com request_id=9                                                                                                                801a23f-72b9-4477-8e90-93fba979e78f fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno= connect= service=                                                                                                                 status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-03-21T20:28:23.718785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra                                                                                                                shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=weather-consult.herokuapp.com request_                                                                                                                id=100c960d-b3a1-4374-ae56-52e60b785710 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno= connect= serv                                                                                                                ice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-03-21T20:28:40.702732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st                                                                                                                arting
2017-03-21T20:28:43.480189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b                                                                                                                in/rails server -p 41364 -e production`
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023383+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.2 application starting                                                                                                                 in production on http://0.0.0.0:41364
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023384+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s                                                                                                                tartup options
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023369+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023384+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023457+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/                                                                                                                activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specificatio                                                                                                                n.rb:176:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but t                                                                                                                he gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is                                                                                                                 at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_spec                                                                                                                ification.rb:173:in `spec'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `estab                                                                                                                lish_connection'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023487+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels)                                                                                                                 in <class:Railtie>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023531+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023532+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_loa                                                                                                                d_hooks'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023526+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `instanc                                                                                                                e_eval'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `execute                                                                                                                _hook'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023534+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecor                                                                                                                d>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023528+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block i                                                                                                                n run_load_hooks'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023535+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/application                                                                                                                _record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023569+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in l                                                                                                                oad_interlock'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023564+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in                                                                                                                 require'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023590+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `                                                                                                                block in loading'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023565+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_depe                                                                                                                ndency'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023590+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in                                                                                                                 `exclusive'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023566+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in                                                                                                                 require_or_load'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023591+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `                                                                                                                loading'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023592+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_inter                                                                                                                lock'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023593+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_o                                                                                                                r_load'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023599+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023598+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023600+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023594+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on                                                                                                                '
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023594+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_d                                                                                                                ependency'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023595+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa                                                                                                                d!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023602+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023603+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023605+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module                                                                                                                :Finisher>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023606+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023626+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen                                                                                                                t'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023608+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023639+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023610+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize                                                                                                                rs'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023641+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:                                                                                                                5:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023651+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023653+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/                                                                                                                ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023665+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `requir                                                                                                                e_relative'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023655+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023671+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block                                                                                                                 in <main>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023661+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023675+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023678+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023683+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023696+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023685+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023700+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023687+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023690+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023702+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023704+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023710+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023712+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in serv                                                                                                                er'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023714+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023715+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023724+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023718+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2                                                                                                                .0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023726+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.023732+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2017-03-21T20:28:48.114357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-21T20:28:48.128920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c                                                                                                                rashed
2017-03-21T20:28:49.680428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra                                                                                                                shed" method=GET path="/recipes" host=weather-consult.herokuapp.com request_id=a                                                                                                                42f1683-8c92-412e-bc36-35bee47fd044 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno= connect= service=                                                                                                                 status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-03-21T20:28:50.139167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra                                                                                                                shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=weather-consult.herokuapp.com request_                                                                                                                id=70b71bcf-af11-489f-bdee-f3325249f7fe fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno= connect= serv                                                                                                                ice= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I think you don't have `gem 'pg'` in your Gemfile. Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems

Comment: @KevinEtore yes i have it.
`
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
`

Comment: I managed to fix the problem now. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You must not have pg in your Gemfile which makes me think that you might be missing deployment specific stuff from your gemfile. Find the `sqlite3` or equivalent development database gem and restructure it like this in your gemfile, which is typically how its done. Heroku automagically looks for that :production environment and loads the applicable configs for that.

```
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'letsencrypt-rails-heroku'
end
```

You also sometimes get that error when you forget to migrate the database when your schema changes. You can do that with `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart dynos.

`heroku ps:restart`

or try simply `heroku restart`

Description: [Devcenter Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes)

This also can by helpful
[Heroku deployment error H10 (App crashed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your logs in the question so they are a bit more readable. You need to add pg to your Gemfile as you are using Postgresql.

```
The gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).(Gem::LoadError)
```