# Node.js Heroku deployment error (application crash)

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack

My application works locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku I get this log. I don't know how to fix it.
heroku local (works as intended) i can run the up locally, the error is when i deploy it
I included the full error list(copied from the terminal).

```
        2017-03-30T00:52:03.538114+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
        2017-03-30T00:52:06.692771+00:00 app[web.1]:
        2017-03-30T00:52:06.692786+00:00 app[web.1]: > bookFace@0.0.1 start /app
        2017-03-30T00:52:06.692786+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
        2017-03-30T00:52:06.692787+00:00 app[web.1]:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892784+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:640
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892799+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892800+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892801+00:00 app[web.1]:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892806+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app_client/common/filters/addHtmlLineBreaks.filter.js'
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addFile (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:85:22)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892809+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:104:17
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892810+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892811+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.UglifyJS.minify (/app/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:102:26)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892811+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:44:25)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892814+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.892815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/bin/www:7:11)
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.917962+00:00 app[web.1]:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.933134+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.933373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.933558+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.9.5
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934231+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934233+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! bookFace@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934450+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the bookFace@0.0.1 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934561+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934667+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bookFace package,
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934811+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.934985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs bookFace
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935588+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls bookFace
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.935848+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.941117+00:00 app[web.1]:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.941343+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
        2017-03-30T00:52:08.941489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
        2017-03-30T00:52:09.045132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
        2017-03-30T00:52:09.059105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
        2017-03-30T00:52:21.613199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=2a55e09f-51db-4d34-82d2-5bf724899e95 fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
        2017-03-30T00:52:23.316363+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=f0d4cbb7-78f4-4d45-b167-c0ebf3811a13 fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
        2017-03-30T00:52:25.284143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=2a9756c8-be31-4475-a06d-d520e1ddf082 fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
        2017-03-30T00:52:26.126666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pacific-bastion-15276.herokuapp.com request_id=c243bd0f-31d0-467c-8b7b-62bb6e5ad12b fwd="80.1.102.64" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: similar issue with "h10"  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed   verify that you in correct directory to start node  ... maybe add a "cd" before calling node exec

Comment: i checked the solution you mentioned but mine is a node.js app and none of the solutions specified there works for me, plus i even run "heroku local web" which works fine on my machine. just couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: if "heroku local"  works on localhost yet you get an H10 on a remote heroku deploy, the details should be in the heroku log for the remote deploy.  this will be in the console where u call "git push heroku master"

Comment: First off all thank you for your help,

and this is what i get copied from the terminal

Comment: review your build process and why the file not found :: addHtmlLineBreaks.filter.js  wild guess is that u have some buildpack and or integration issue with "mean-stack" // grunt build