# heroku app keeps crashing with error code=h10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, crash, production, puma

I'm really mystified with this one. Does my app need a procfile for puma?

puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count

    port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

   environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

  plugin :tmp_restart
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.3.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'devise'
gem 'tinymce-rails-imageupload', github: 'PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
 gem 'mini_magick'
 gem 'carrierwave'
 gem 'fog'
 gem 'figaro'


 gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
 gem 'bootstrap'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'mini_racer'

 gem 'stripe'
 gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
 gem 'activestorage'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Books4reviews
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2



    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

  end
end
```

Here's the Herku logs:

```
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192457+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `instance_eval'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192461+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:71:in `block in execute_hook'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192463+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192464+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192465+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192471+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.1/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:206:in `<class:Blob>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192472+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.1/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:16:in `<main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192475+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192479+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192480+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192481+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192482+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192483+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192484+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192487+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192488+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:374:in `block in require_or_load'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192490+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192493+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192495+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192522+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:352:in `require_or_load'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:46:in `block in require_or_load'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192549+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:45:in `require_or_load'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192550+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `depend_on'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192553+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `depend_on'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192555+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:244:in `require_dependency'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192578+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:478:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192591+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192593+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:477:in `block in eager_load!'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192598+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192599+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `eager_load!'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192600+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:356:in `eager_load!'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192601+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192602+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192603+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192605+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192607+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192608+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192609+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192612+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192613+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192620+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192622+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192645+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192646+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192647+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192650+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192651+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192657+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192660+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192662+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192667+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192688+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192691+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192695+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192714+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192716+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192718+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192725+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192728+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192729+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192731+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192757+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192759+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192760+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192765+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192766+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192768+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192772+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53:in `start'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192773+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192776+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192777+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192779+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192781+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192802+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192803+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192806+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192807+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192814+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192815+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192818+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192819+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192821+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192823+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192852+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192854+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.192856+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-10-24T00:50:57.213969+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-10-24T00:50:57.213977+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.1 application starting in production
2018-10-24T00:50:57.213979+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-10-24T00:50:57.213980+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-10-24T00:50:57.786631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=ae9a447e-0f0b-4dc7-a9ba-fa10929270b6 fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T00:50:57.981941+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=5f22c727-b4fd-48b2-b871-e39badb1145f fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T00:54:13.725572+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=f76c2a62-a09f-41b4-9479-637580d3a108 fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T00:54:13.550977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/sign_out" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=32c7386a-bd68-4778-bf07-92ea5a851666 fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T00:55:43.179259+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/books" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=b2d24bf4-f8c2-42fb-9fc9-52ac24c8da73 fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-24T00:55:43.355964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-river-21214.herokuapp.com request_id=ba22adb2-b5d0-4b53-add0-55b66b18d966 fwd="107.77.222.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The app deploys to Heroku successfully but immediatly crashes when you open it...

I am using postrgresql for the db obviously and puma for the web server. I also use carrierwave, fog and AWS for the assets storage. If there's any files that would be helpful to troubleshoot the error, I'd be happy to include them. This error in the log doesn't help me at all but maybe someone with more experience would understand its ambiguity.

upon closer look in the rails console, I got this error: Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)

Comment: Do you know when this error started to happen? Any change in your code recently ?

Comment: before I was using fog and aws for my file uploads the app didn't crash. And then when I made a file called storage.yml and added my aws access keys it said in rails console in the heroku CLI that Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)

Comment: It is quite a generic error. You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed there are a few options. If it doesn't help fix, it may at least direct you or give more info on the possible problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that heroku requires a Procfile without an extension: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
The typical procfile looks something like this: `web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm having an issues with active storage though. I added the procfile without an extension. I get this error in the rails console: <class:Engine>': Couldn't find Active Storage configuration in /app/config/storage.yml (RuntimeError)