# Application error on deployed app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, production

please help, i have no idea. I am getting this from my heroku logs.

i am on ruby 2.3
rails 5.1

```
2019-03-20T15:05:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-20T15:05:53.943996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-reef-51265.herokuapp.com request_id=5c0b7d49-b20e-4469-a483-88093fd77f5e fwd="41.66.199.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-20T15:05:54.781463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-reef-51265.herokuapp.com request_id=de8a1df2-fc24-4e69-8b36-7cb1e92a73da fwd="41.66.199.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-20T15:05:58.794279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-reef-51265.herokuapp.com request_id=d53446ea-a1bd-474e-ad6c-ddf62b74689f fwd="41.66.199.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-20T15:05:59.021626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-reef-51265.herokuapp.com request_id=63bd925f-fc04-4169-94ce-d08afd620a57 fwd="41.66.199.69" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Comment: Your application crashes (throws an exception.)

Comment: Have you tried `heroku restart` ?
Also you could find more information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed

Comment: yes i have done heroku restart a dozen times

Comment: i checked on the link u sent and i tried the heroku  run rails console, and found an issue =>  `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: but i have the gem in my gem file. => this is it. and have bundle installed  => # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Comment: Please, provide your Gemfile

Comment: @NikitaMisharin   Gemfile =>
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6', '>= 5.1.6.2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

Comment: group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end  gem 'jquery-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `heroku local` or `heroku run rails c`. The first command will try to run the server locally and the second will run the rails console on your heroku server. Both of them should crash because of the error that is causing your heroku app to fail to launch, but they should provide a more detailed explanation as to the cause. I have seen this error a couple times before and one time it was because I wasn't autoloading classes correctly, i.e `require 'devise` in `application.rb` and the other time it was because there was an error in a controller class name.

Comment: $ heroku local
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
4:09:20 PM web.1 |  npm
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
4:09:20 PM web.1 |   ERR! missing script: start
4:09:20 PM web.1 |  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
4:09:20 PM web.1 |  npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-20T16_09_20_215Z-debug.log
4:09:20 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null

Comment: What's in your Procfile?

Comment: @Micheal Callahan please i think i can't find the procfile in my app

Comment: It is in the root of your project, if you don't have one you'll have to create one. There is documentation at Heroku's Dev Center

Comment: $heroku local
9:17:01 AM web.1 |  *** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable! 9:17:01 AM web.1 |  *** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable! 9:17:01 AM web.1 |  *** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
9:17:01 AM web.1 |  Puma starting in single mode...
9:17:01 AM web.1 |  * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Llamas in Pajamas 9:17:01 AM web.1 |  * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5 9:17:01 AM web.1 |  * Environment: development 9:17:05 AM web.1 |  * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000 9:17:05 AM web.1 |  Use Ctrl-C to stop

Comment: Can someone please help me understand this?? i run                               $heroku ps
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 945h 29m (94%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 4m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: crashed 2019/03/21 09:36:31 +0000 (~ 12m ago)