# I was trying to deploy my python and django project on heroku and facing this error in log files

Tags: python, django, heroku

```
2020-02-21T05:05:20.221933+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
host=bollymovierecommender.herokuapp.com
request_id=caa9375b-25d0-4f7b-8049-f308bd5dc83e fwd="49.207.108.233"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-02-21T05:05:21.521664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
host=bollymovierecommender.herokuapp.com
request_id=67596e3f-cd06-479e-aa31-7e0fcf5a879b fwd="49.207.108.233"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can anyone help me understand what is this error?

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes
You are getting the error H10 App crashed. The problem could be anything.

Sadly the error log isn't helpful here. It looks like you did define a Procfile and you did bind to the $PORT (else you'd be seeing a different error message).

There has been a similar question about it here: [Heroku deployment error H10 (App crashed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed)

> I ran into the same error above, app was crashing on heroku (running
>   fine in dev) but error logs on heroku were not revealing any clues. I
>   read other answers on this page and broke out in a sweat after seeing
>   "rebuilding the app." I figured maybe I could get in the heroku
>   console and look around. I did and even the console crashed, but this
>   time it told me why. It was some obscure variable I forgot to delete
>   during a troubleshooting session hours earlier. I am not saying you
>   will run into the same problem, but I found more info when I tried to
>   go through the console. Hope this helps.
>
> `$ heroku run rails console`

With this you can get a better error log pointing you towards the problem.