# Rails tutorial SampleApp runs fine local in developement, but crashes at startup on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

Thanks for taking a look. I'm trying to finish up Ruby on Rails Tutorial, but for some reason while my app runs fine local, when i try and access the production version on heroku it crashes before even loading. i'm not sure where to start looking... here's the log if anyone might be able to help with any idea on where to even start.

2021-03-13T22:41:06.389322+00:00 heroku[run.7568]: Awaiting client
2021-03-13T22:41:06.414584+00:00 heroku[run.7568]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2021-03-13T22:41:16.311084+00:00 heroku[run.7568]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-13T22:41:16.388759+00:00 heroku[run.7568]: State changed from up to complete
2021-03-13T22:41:31.529943+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed` by user *
2021-03-13T22:41:40.880732+00:00 heroku[run.5245]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-13T22:41:41.165110+00:00 heroku[run.5245]: Awaiting client
2021-03-13T22:41:41.221261+00:00 heroku[run.5245]: Starting process with command `rails db:seed`
2021-03-13T22:42:59.106396+00:00 heroku[run.5245]: Process exited with status 0
2021-03-13T22:42:59.165393+00:00 heroku[run.5245]: State changed from up to complete
2021-03-13T22:52:28.536182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calm-hamlet-33169.herokuapp.com request_id=f7b0e58e-a195-40f1-a42d-0bc26838be59 fwd="97.84.97.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-13T22:52:28.706184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calm-hamlet-33169.herokuapp.com request_id=411ec890-c009-44a4-96b5-2c0f0a64b8f1 fwd="97.84.97.216" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24113266/4722345

Comment: Did you successfully run the migrations to set up the DB yet?  `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?  Or do you need to seed the DB after that to have some initial data, `heroku run rake db:seed` ?  Are there any errors produced from which ever step you are on?