# Deploy Django app to Heroku end with Error

Tags: django, heroku

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Log file:

```
2022-01-25T09:56:52.826338+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2022-01-25T09:56:52.826405+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2022-01-25T09:56:52.826413+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2022-01-25T09:56:52.826514+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2022-01-25T09:56:52.826544+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2022-01-25T09:56:53.005213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-25T09:56:53.060263+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-25T09:56:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-25T09:57:06.746469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheikhshahed.herokuapp.com request_id=5096cca5-60ee-4038-b90a-30ab5d4b13fe fwd="106.0.54.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-25T09:57:07.638428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheikhshahed.herokuapp.com request_id=245c9fab-4633-4387-805b-3255291496c6 fwd="106.0.54.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496827/heroku-deployment-error-h10-app-crashed

Comment: That's just the last few lines of the error. Please [edit] your question and add _all_ of it, not just the part you think is important.